# Getting database connection in Spring Batch service classes

Tags: spring-batch

I have a few cases where I want to get a connection to a configured database in a Spring Batch service class, for example in a processor or a custom writer.  I can inject the data source into my class but I want to get a connection to it.  The out of the box Spring Batch database readers and writers automagically get a connection so I want to use that rather than write my own connection code.  So in the writer example say my class uses ItemWriterAdapter and in it I need to do a query.  How can I grab an established connection to a configured data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your context.xml (assuming dataSource bean is defined)

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

In your Writer or Processor, inject this jdbcTemplate

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Now you may query with Spring Jdbc using the same datasource http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html